# How can I parse a website with PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I want to make a website with news just like my other site appears on the Internet.

I haven't got enough content. So I want to get content from another news website (Of course, I got permission to copy their content from their site).

For this I used [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net), and it's progressing very well on my other site, but as I apply my script on the release site, it doesn't work (outputs nothing).

Here is the link I want to get the data from: [hesspress.com](http://hesspress.com).

**Code:**

```php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$lien='http://www.hesspress.com';
$html=new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($lien);
$k=$html->find('a',0)->href;
print_r($k);
```

Comment: So you want to get the first link on the page?

Comment: No it's just a test to see if my script manages to get the flow of html site after I will handle the rest

Comment: It is possible that your release server has getting webpages through `file_get_contents` disabled. In that case, you would have to use cURL, like in my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't use your this code in your website you can do it if you use this link  http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 5):

This is what I would use, you can modify it for your own purposes.

It uses the [built-in PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

**Code:**

```
<?php
$url = 'http://acid3.acidtests.org';
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($handle);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Prevent HTML errors from displaying
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$link = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
echo 'Link text: ' . $link->nodeValue;
echo '<br />';
echo 'Link URL: ' . $link->getAttribute('href');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you it works but I do not know why it gives this Warning

These are the Warning

    
    Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: ID box_opinions already defined in Entity, line: 578 in C:\wamp\www\parse.php on line 8
    
    Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: ID mainTicker already defined in Entity, line: 579 in C:\wamp\www\parse.php on line 8
    

    Link text: ÙØ§Ù ÙØ£Ø¹ÙØ§Ù 
    Link URL: /economie/index.1.html

Comment: @TiAmoLaky That's because the page is coded badly. I've updated my answer to ignore errors.